# How is AutomationId set up

Tags: c#, wpf, automated-tests, ui-automation

I use UI Automation to automate testing of WPF application and I faced with strange behavior of **AutomationId** property for Window element. I specified **x:Uid** property with the value **'Window_1'** in XAML for the Window element. I expect that **AutomationId** is **'Window_1'**. But it's not so. The value of AutomationId can be empty **''** or be equal to the expected value. It's not deterministic. But **Inspect.exe** always displays AutomationId is set to **'Window_1'**.  If I specify **AutomationProperties.AutomationId** in XAML explicitly, it also does not work.

A little bit about my application. It is a console application but it can run WPF UI using Dispatcher.Run.  I use **TreeWalker.RawViewWalker** and **AutomationElement.Current.AutomationId** to find desired element in automated tests.

So, my question is how UI Automation set the value of AutomationId of the element? Why specifying Uid does not work, and specifying AutomationProperties.AutomationId does?

Comment: Are you  by any chance accessing its automation element the moment the component appears on screen? UIA can be a bit slow to update its model sometimes. Do you see the same behavior if you wait a bit and then try to retrieve the value again?

Comment: Hi Alex, if I wait for several seconds, UI Automation is able to recognize the desired AutomationId. And how AutomationId works, it looks to me as some kind of magic )